# How to define a cell's content based on the contents of an object's attribute using setCellFactory?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I've created a class called "ChatMessage" with 3 attributes:

```
a) timeOfMessage
b) sentOrReceived
c) message
```

and chat messages are stored inside an array of ChatMessages.
I've defined a tableView, and 3 tableColumns (for a, b and c), like so:

```
// ------------------------
// Step 1: Define tableView
// ------------------------
@FXML private TableView<ChatMessage> tableViewAllMessages;

// ---------------------------
// Step 2: Define table's data
// ---------------------------
private ObservableList<ChatMessage> allMessagesList;

// --------------------------------
// Step 3: Define table's 3 columns
// --------------------------------
@FXML private TableColumn<ChatMessage, LocalDateTime> timeColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<ChatMessage, Boolean> sentOrReceivedColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<ChatMessage, String> messageColumn;

// ---------------------------------
// Step 4: Using setCellValueFactory
// ---------------------------------
timeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ChatMessage,LocalDateTime>("dateTime"));
sentOrReceivedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ChatMessage, Boolean>("sentOrReceived"));
messageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ChatMessage,String>("message"));
tableViewAllMessages.setItems(allMessagesList);
```

Everything works fine!
However, I would like to turn sentOrReceivedColumn (in Step 2), which currently of a boolean value, into a string value, based on the true/false it returns.
Is there a way to make a cell write 'someStringA' when `false` and 'someStringB' when `true`?
To be more specific, what do I need to change in here:

```
sentOrReceivedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ChatMessage, Boolean>("sentOrReceived"));
```

or maybe add a line like this:

```
sentOrReceivedColumn.setCellFactory(/* But what Do I write here? */);
```

?

```
// Here is my ChatMessage Class:
public class ChatMessage {
    private Customer customer;
    private int messageNumber;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private String message;
    private boolean sentOrReceived;

    public ChatMessage(Customer customer, int messageNumber, LocalDateTime dateTime, String message, boolean sentOrReceived) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.messageNumber = messageNumber;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.message = message;
        this.sentOrReceived = sentOrReceived;
    }
}
```

Comment: The cell value factory is just a `Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>>`, which means you can implement your own factory that maps the value with just a lambda expression. Note you'll have to change the type arguments of the column to `TableColumn<ChatMessage, OtherType>`. That said, it may be easier (and possibly more appropriate) to use a [cell factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) for this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Slaw** for your comment! It steered me in the right direction.
I implemented my own factory that maps the value with just a lambda expression as you suggested. This was the answer I was looking for:

```
col2_Nickname.setCellFactory(lambda -> new TableCell<ChatMessage, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Boolean sentOrReceived, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(sentOrReceived, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                }else{
                    setText(sentOrReceived ? "MyNickname" : "His/Her nickname");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution using a cell factory. Though kleopatra is probably correct in that changing the model would be the better solution. You mention you don't want to change `ChatMessage` for database reasons, which is understandable, but you could add a sort of "translation" model class (e.g. a _view model_ of sorts). Depending on your application design this may require adding another layer of abstraction or at least "glue code", which may or may not be acceptable to you.

Comment: be careful with gender assumptions - they could be construed as being offensive if wrong (as yours is <g>) And no, not possible to edit comments (except in the first couple of minutes), looks like some have been deleted.